# $global: is set in a PowerShell session but not in the System.Management.Automation.PowerShell instance

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

I'm moving the execution of a PowerShell script (StartBackup.ps1) that we would normally run in a standalone PowerShell session into a C# application. The script executes normally directly in PowerShell, imports modules/DLLs, calls into other scripts and sets a ton of variables.

In the C# application, I have:

```
using (PowerShell powerShell = PowerShell.Create())
{
    powerShell.AddCommand("Set-ExecutionPolicy");
    powerShell.AddParameter("Scope", "Process");
    powerShell.AddParameter("ExecutionPolicy", "RemoteSigned");

    powerShell.AddCommand("Set-Location");
    powerShell.AddParameter("Path", "E:\\BackupTools");

    powerShell.AddCommand("E:\\BackupTools\\StartBackup.ps1", false);
    powerShell.AddParameter("Type", "Closed");

    Collection<PSObject> results = powerShell.Invoke();

    foreach (var resultItem in results)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

The above runs just fine up until the point where $global: stuff gets set, and that's where it starts to throw errors. All of those values are null/empty.

I added a couple of powerShell.AddCommands to check whether or not those values are set after the script executes, and they are indeed all null in the PowerShell instance. In the standalone shell they're all set just fine.

What is the issue here? Why is the PowerShell instance different from an actual shell?

EDIT: The intention is not to just fire-and-forget the script. The intention is to have it do its job and then continue working with whatever artifacts it leaves behind in the PowerShell instance just as I normally would if this was powershell.exe.

Comment: You haven't shown where the $global stuff gets set or the errors.

Comment: Your `Set-Location` command have no effect, that may cause your problems. But without [mcve] it is hard to say something for certain.

Comment: @PetSerAl, could you elaborate on why it has no effect?

Comment: The pipeline, you are building with `PowerShell` class, looks like this: `Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope: Process -ExecutionPolicy: RemoteSigned | Set-Location -Path: E:\BackupTools | . E:\\BackupTools\\StartBackup.ps1 -Type: Closed`. Try to run it in "actual shell" and see the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to just execute an existing PowerShell script, the simplest way would be to use the [Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=netframework-4.7) class. You can build the command line and run it.

The C# PowerShell Class is required if you want to build your script itself in your C# code.

Also, your `AddCommand` will chain the commands. Is that your requirement ?

[MSDN post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kebab/2014/04/28/executing-powershell-scripts-from-c/)

> Call AddCommand() methods to add this content to **the execution pipeline**.

```
using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
{
    // use "AddScript" to add the contents of a script file to the end of the execution pipeline.
    // use "AddCommand" to add individual commands/cmdlets to the end of the execution pipeline.
    PowerShellInstance.AddScript("param($param1) $d = get-date; $s = 'test string value'; " +
            "$d; $s; $param1; get-service");

    // use "AddParameter" to add a single parameter to the last command/script on the pipeline.
    PowerShellInstance.AddParameter("param1", "parameter 1 value!");
}
```

Comment: This was a tremendous blunder on my part. The $global stuff was indeed set externally. I didn't have PowerShell.Invoker() between the policy, path and the final script commands.